# Why is my function not looping with no errors showing?

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I am following a book tutorial on Javascript, in which I should wite a hangman game using only functions, I am near the end but and I can't figure this one out... For some reason my function is not looping, specifically, my prompt massage cant gets by my first letter/input, after that, I can't get any more prompt massages.. because It should, that is the loop for implemented... I know this is vary basic problem, but I just can't get pass this through. If somebody just take a look at it, it would be nice...

I have tried using "console.log" and put it inside "if" statement and inside "for" loop, to see if the loop is working, the loop is working but my prompt is not looping/recurring... And I don't know why... :(

```js
var updateGameState = function (guess, word, answerArray) {
// Update answerArray and return a number showing how many
// times the guess appears in the word so remainingLetters
// can be updated


    for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
            if (word[j] === guess && answerArray[j] !== word[j]) {
                answerArray[j] = guess;
                remainingLetters--;

                };

    }; getGuess();
        console.log(answerArray);   


};

var remainingLetters = word.length;
var correctGuesses = updateGameState(guess, word, answerArray);
```

Right now I only want that my prompt message keeps popping up so long that I can input my letters/guesses...

----Down below is the .js and html file....----

```js
var pickWord = function(random) {
  // Return a random word
  return random[Math.floor(Math.random() * random.length)];

};

var word = pickWord(["fakultet", "zirafa", "trava", "labelo"]);
console.log(word);

var setupAnswerArray = function(word) {
  // Return the answer array
  var answerArray = [];
  for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    answerArray[i] = "_";
  }
  console.log(answerArray);
  return answerArray;
};
var answerArray = setupAnswerArray(word);

var showPlayerProgress = function(answerArray) {
  // Use alert to show the player their progress
  return alert(answerArray.join(" "));

};
showPlayerProgress(answerArray);

var getGuess = function() {
  // Use prompt to get a guess
  return (prompt("Guess a letter, or click Cancel to stop playing " + answerArray)).toLowerCase();
};
var guess = getGuess();
console.log(guess);

//               HERE IS THE PROBLEM
///*******************************************************
var updateGameState = function(guess, word, answerArray) {
  // Update answerArray and return a number showing how many
  // times the guess appears in the word so remainingLetters
  // can be updated
  for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
    if (word[j] === guess && answerArray[j] !== word[j]) {
      answerArray[j] = guess;
      remainingLetters--;
    };
  };
  getGuess();
  console.log(answerArray);
};

var remainingLetters = word.length;
var correctGuesses = updateGameState(guess, word, answerArray);
//*********************************************************


/* - code from the book

var showAnswerAndCongratulatePlayer = function (answerArray) {
// Use alert to show the answer and congratulate the player
};

var word = pickWord();
var answerArray = setupAnswerArray(word);
var remainingLetters = word.length;
while (remainingLetters > 0) {
showPlayerProgress(answerArray);
var guess = getGuess();
if (guess === null) {
break;
} else if (guess.length !== 1) {
alert("Please enter a single letter.");
} else {
var correctGuesses = updateGameState(guess, word, answerArray);
remainingLetters -= correctGuesses;
}
}
showAnswerAndCongratulatePlayer(answerArray);


*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Section 2: JavaScript Language Basics</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Section 2: JavaScript Language Basics</h1>
</body>

<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to call `updateGameState()` in a loop until all the letters are guessed.

Comment: Why do you expect it to loop if you haven't written a loop?

Comment: Well, I have wrote it inside the function...

Comment: @Antonio yes but that's only for looping letters within a word to check if the user guessed one. The loop you haven't written is the one that you need - in order to keep asking for more guesses. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop round and round until the number of letters remaining is 0. Right now you ask for a guess, update the state once, and then ask for one more guess and stop.

It might make sense to encapsulate the process of asking for a guess and then updating the state into another function. Then you can keep calling that function until the user wins. I also moved all the calls to functions etc (i.e. the liner part of the code) into one block so it's clear. When it was dotted in amongst the various functions it was hard to follow the flow of the program.

Demo:

```js
var pickWord = function(random) {
  // Return a random word
  return random[Math.floor(Math.random() * random.length)];
};

var setupAnswerArray = function(word) {
  // Return the answer array
  var answerArray = [];
  for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    answerArray[i] = "_";
  }
  console.log(answerArray);
  return answerArray;
};

var getGuess = function() {
  // Use prompt to get a guess
  return (prompt("Guess a letter, or click Cancel to stop playing " + answerArray)).toLowerCase();
};

var updateGameState = function(guess, word, answerArray) {
  // Update answerArray and return a number showing how many
  // times the guess appears in the word so remainingLetters
  // can be updated
  for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
    if (word[j] === guess && answerArray[j] !== word[j]) {
      answerArray[j] = guess;
      remainingLetters--;
    };
  };
  console.log(answerArray);
};

function play() {
  var guess = getGuess();
  console.log(guess);
  updateGameState(guess, word, answerArray);
}

var word = pickWord(["fakultet", "zirafa", "trava", "labelo"]);
console.log(word);
var answerArray = setupAnswerArray(word);
var remainingLetters = word.length;
while (remainingLetters > 0) {
  play();
}

alert("You win - congratulations");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Section 2: JavaScript Language Basics</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Section 2: JavaScript Language Basics</h1>
</body>

<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```